# MAMP / MAMP Pro database conflicts

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, mamp, mamp-pro

I sometimes get the databases in phpMyAdmin that are stored under /Library/Application Support/appsolute/db/mysql, this should be the path for MAMP PRO. However, I don't use MAMP PRO. I have tried the trial once, and continued using the free version.

However, sometimes I get the databases visible under /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql, they are a bit off, and I am missing a database there I was working on the other day, but the database is visible in the MAMP Pro database.

I have tried copying the database to the MAMP free database folder, but this results in giving errors in phpMyAdmin. It does show the tables in the database, but it cant display the structure of the tables.

---

Update:

Still experiencing this issue. Right now I just started my Mac and started MAMP, wanted to continue working on a project and it loads the other database (I think this is the database stored in MAMP Pro), when yesterday it was loading the MAMP databases.

I have no idea how and why this is happening, and how I can find the issue.

---

Long story short: MAMP uses the MAMP Pro databases sometimes in `/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql` instead of `/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/`, note that I don't have MAMP Pro, I have the regular MAMP. Sometimes it uses the MAMP database folder, sometimes it uses the MAMP Pro databases folder.

Comment: Couldn't this be related to paths? Remove the MAMP PRO path from your system, doesn't that help? If you don't have MAMP PRO why then does that location exist? `/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql`

Answer (score 2):

MAMP is using this mysql database:
/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql

MAMP PRO is using this databse:
/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql

this may help I'm not too sure - your databases should be in either one

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a path related issue.

Check your system paths and fix any errors that are pointing to MAMP Pro.

Also, check your MAMP conf file and see how the datadir is set, is it set to the MAMP Pro location ?

---

*SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir';*

*datadir - /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql/*

An example of a custom conf file used to change this

`default-storage-engine=MyISAM
innodb=OFF
datadir=/Users/someuser/drive/mysql/`

Let me know in the comments if this helps and we can work out the error as we go along, I'll edit the answer accordingly if need be.